# IDLE can't find my modules but when I run script from command prompt it does

Tags: python, python-module

I'm trying to install some python modules like pandas, I installed them using pip but It still doesn't show up in the IDLE. But when I run python in command prompt it works fine.

Comment: did you try to restart the IDLE?
Otherwise it looks like you might have multiple interpreters installed - one of them has your libraries, the other (that IDLE uses) doesn't

Answer (score 0):

You probably have more interpreters installed throughout the system.

First, try `pip list` to check if the modules were actually installed

Second of all try `where python` to see where all of the interpreters are installed, and
`Python --version` to see which one you're using

if not, I recommend working in virtual environments [check this for info](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html). Just create a new Virtual Env for the project you're working on, and install there all of the packages you need